# Show WP content on different PHP Sites

Tags: customization, database, dashboard, content, api

we are about to start developing a big dynamic web project (Probably on ZF2) which will have some modules&tabs to act as CMS module (displaying news, galleries, posts etc). Let's assume we have five tabs on main menu, one or two of those tabs will contain this CMS related content. Now my question is, **is it possible to use Wordpress' Admin panel to add content but display it on a different site (not as iframe or widget), if yes how can we do that**.

**Additional note over comment:** There will be user interaction on Zend Application's interface, user must have ability to interact with the content comes from WP side. For example, if he/she changes the topic(category) related news/post must be listed. Which means, ZF2 must make queries to WP Engine.

A screenshot papper of my scenerio is below, please share any idea 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean like RSS feeds? (You can customize feeds to do almost anything.)

Comment: @BA_Webimax You mean i must make wp act as a RSS feed and display that content on my APP? If so it wont solve my issue, because there will be som dynamic fiters, choises on the user interface, for example, a use may chose just a topic(category) and just that topic may be listed on the Zend interface.

Comment: You might want to reread this... http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds You can do almost anything with feeds. Including custom queries. You can pull them in via cURL requests in PHP and you can dynamically update via AJAX if you desire. If you CAN'T do this with a feed. You need to explain why. If that first page doesn't let you get to your desired level of customization, you can go to this page to see how you can turn it into a "anything you want output into an RSS format"... http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds

Comment: @BA_Webimax that sounds reasonable, i shall have a look. I wondered if it is possible, didn't code at all yet. Thanks